# How to draw UI elements with Visual Styles turned off?

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview, ownerdrawn

I have a owner drawn control where I need to draw the expand box ("plus/minus") of a treeview. With visual styles turned on it is easy, just create a renderer for the appropriate *VisualStyleElement*:

```
VisualStyleElement element = VisualStyleElement.TreeView.Glyph.Opened
VisualStyleRenderer renderer = new VisualStyleRenderer( element );
Size size = renderer.GetPartSize( graphics, ThemeSizeType.True );
...
renderer.DrawBackground( graphics, someRect );
```

Is it possible to achieve a similar effect when visual styles are off? I know there is a *ControlPaint* class which can draw entire controls, but how do I draw (and get the size of) just a part of the *TreeView* control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without VisualStyles, I think the plus minus controls are just DrawRectangle and DrawLine method calls.

The Rectangle part looks like it uses the `SystemColors.Control` color, and the Plus/Minus part looks like `SystemColors.ControlText` (or black).

[image]

Comment: I was hoping for some "higher-level" approach, but this works correctly.